# sharethis buttons disappearing in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, sharethis

I have installed the ShareThis module in Drupal 7 on my site, but when I reload my pages, the buttons disappear. There seems to be information on the Drupal forums that explain how to fix this issue with javascript, but I'm unclear which file to put the code in.

http://drupal.org/node/1197104#comment-6636050
http://drupal.org/node/322808#comment-7357744

(p.s. I'm not using the Views module)

Comment: How do you add the snippet ? In the sharethis config page, you can choose "content", "block" or "links"

Comment: I put it in content (book pages and blog posts)

Answer (score 1):

If it is issue of JavaScript or ajax then below solution work perfectly.See below code. this code add in JavaScript file(theme or module).

```
Drupal.behaviors.my_custom_behavior = {
 attach: function (context, settings) {
   var url = window.location.href;
   var urls  = url.split('/').pop().split('.').shift();
    if (urls  == 'abc') {
        stButtons.locateElements(); 
     }

};
};
```

Note: Above example is only particular page.if want to use it globally remove **if** condition.